# Event not waiting for user answer inside dialog

Tags: angularjs, events, ngroute, preventdefault, mddialog

I need the user to confirm leaving the page if a specific condition is fulfilled. The problem is the location change is not waiting for the dialog to get the user answer.

Here's my code:

angular module 1:

```
...
function confirmLeavePage(e, newUrl) {
        if(form.cod.value) {
            customDialog.confirmDialog('Title','Leave?').then(
            function(){
                console.log('go to selected page');
            },function(){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", confirmLeavePage);
...
```

angular module 2 :

```
angular.module('dialog').service('customDialog', function($mdDialog, $q, $location) {

    this.confirmDialog = function(title, content){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $mdDialog.show($mdDialog.confirm({
            templateUrl:'confirmDialog.html',
            title : title,
            textContent : content,
            ok : 'Confirm',
            cancel: 'Cancel'
        })).then(function() {
            console.log('confirmed');
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function() {
           console.log('abort');
           deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise; 
    }


});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function confirmLeavePage(e, newUrl) {
        if(form.cod.value) {
            customDialog.confirmDialog('Title','Leave?').then(
            function(){
                console.log('go to selected page');
            });
        }

         e.preventDefault();
         return;
    }
```

Comment: I replaced 
`console.log('go to selected page');`
with
`$location.path(newUrl)`
but it triggers the dialog again since it's caught by
`$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", confirmLeavePage);`
Any ideas?